# Почему теряются данные в JSON строке при POST запросе?

Tags: php, json, curl, file-get-contents

Есть сайт на котором динамически подгружается контент посредством AJAX, я восполнил запрос в скрипте двумя способами

1.

```
$url = 'https://lenta.com/api/v1/skus/list';
    $categoryDoc = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create(array
    (
        'http' => array
        (
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" ,           
            'content' => '{"nodeCode":"cf0349a2de3bac83f8d359ff8b960c798","filters":[],"tag":"","typeSearch":1,"pricesRange":null,"sortingType":"ByPriority","offset":24,"limit":24}'
        )
    )));
```

2. 

```
$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"nodeCode":"cf0349a2de3bac83f8d359ff8b960c798","filters":[],"tag":"","typeSearch":1,"pricesRange":null,"sortingType":"ByPriority","offset":24,"limit":24}' );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

В обоих случаях результат такой:

```
{"skus":[],"limit":24,"offset":24,"totalCount":21}
```

В то время как в браузере в Response следующее:

```
{"skus":[{"code":"463892_10","brand":"ИНДИЛАЙТ"}],"limit":24,"offset":24,"totalCount":21}
```

Информация в **skus** очень важна, и она теряется почему-то, остаются только квадратные скобки. Почему так происходит? Как это исправить?

Comment: Вероятно вы не всё воспроизвели для получения идентичного ответа. Наверняка есть и заголовки, передаваемые браузером, кроме тела запроса?

Comment: Проверил второй вариант на локальной машине - выплевывает длинный ответ с перечнем всех skus. Проверьте, что нет очепяток в вашей версии кода.

Кстати, как вы через браузер POST запрос отправляли то?

Comment: @Johny вы проверяли второй вариант через консоль? Вы передавали только один заголовок "Content-Type:application/json"? Говоря про браузер в своем вопросе я имел ввиду панель разработчика в Chrome.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov да, вы оказались правы! Мой скрипт работает верно, но сервер на который шлется запрос неправильно понимает мое местоположение и отдает не те данные в skus, добавление заголовка Cookie, где явно указан город, исправило ситуацию. При вашем желании, можете разместить это в ответе, с меня зелёная галочка!

Comment: @orel-22 да, проверял через консоль, в CLI режиме. Но вижу что вы уже разобрались с вопросом )))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Передавай в куках данные по магазину. Например эти.
lentaT2=spb; CityCookie=spb; UseCookieNotification=true; Store=0702;